# Should I delete a closed question with answer?

Tags: support

I have a post: [Why is a certain subset not a subspace of $\mathbb{K}_2$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4720995/why-is-a-certain-subset-not-a-subspace-of-mathbbk-2), where it got closed and received downvotes but I have an answer in the post. So, should I delete such post or make the answer better, for example?

Comment: You should make the question better (the answer will take care of itself). Specifically, you need to "Add details and clarify the problem being solved." You should also add some context (where you found the problem, what you know, etc.)

Comment: @user1729 About the context, how can I correctly add where I found the problem and what I know?

Comment: You could add to the start like "I'm studying the module X, and was reading the course book Y. I got stuck on this problem because...." and then explain *why* you got stuck. Maybe it is similar to a problem from your notes/a book, but different enough that you can't translate the solution, or maybe you tried a few things or some examples but got stuck, so explain these. See [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question) for more details.

Comment: This question will go into the reopen queue now, I've voted to reopen it.

Comment: Thank you! Now, the only thing is I don't know whether the answer to the question is correct and I should accept it. I suppose I should as it has an upvote.

Comment: Ideally you should not write the answer unless you're perfectly confident that it's right. In this case, your answer is correct so go on and accept it. The upvote on that answer is mine, for what it's worth

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Making my comments into an answer.

---

You should make the question better (the answer will take care of itself). Specifically, you need to address the close reason of "Add details and clarify the problem being solved."

You should also add some context (where you found the problem, what you know, etc.) For example, you could add to the start something like "I'm studying the module X, and was reading the course book Y. I got stuck on this problem because...." and then explain why you got stuck. Maybe it is similar to a problem from your notes/a book, but different enough that you can't translate the solution, or maybe you tried a few things or some examples but got stuck, so explain these. See [How to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question) for more details.

Comment: Heh, but, in this context, maybe ‘module’ is not the right choice of word for an education unit. 

Comment: [Re](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/35792/should-i-delete-a-closed-question-with-answer/35796#comment168919_35796), it was quite clear, just a funny—"funny ha ha", not "funny strange", as SNL once put it—choice of words when discussing vector spaces.

Comment: @LSpice Ooooh it's been a long year already. I am embarrassed and have deleted my comment! Once upon a time, I had a sense of humour :-(.

Comment: [Re](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/35792/should-i-delete-a-closed-question-with-answer/35796#comment168942_35796), my fault!  Sorry for being obscure, and thanks for going with the joke once it was clear.